# PowerShell, slash in variable

Tags: powershell

I have link like this:

```
\\example.domian\shared\folder1\data
```

I want to find all groups in the AD with some link e.g. above in notes field

So

```
$link = "\\\example.domian\shared\folder1\data"
$find = "*$link*"

Get-adgroup -filter {info -like $find} -properties name, info, description | select name, info, description
```

And it find nothing. Of course the group exists with this link in note field.

I think the problem is in the slash, because it is a special characters but I can't find solutions.

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @Stijn Please review your edit: you have put an extra backslash in there which was not in the original question I think.

Comment: @Theo Possibly, OP kept editing the question while I was trying to fix the formatting. OP can correct the issue if necessary.

Comment: You will see that `$link -like $find` returns true. So the question is, what are the **actual** values of "info"?

Comment: I didn't add any backslashes though, I removed one because I was certain it wasn't there in the original question. See the revision markdown diff.

Comment: @Stijn Ok, maybe I saw it the other way around then.. I can remove the comment if you like.

Answer (score 0):

surely you would be better doing something like the below in your Get-Adgroup command:

```
-Searchbase "DistinguishedNameOfOUtoSearch"
```